# How to read all recurring events from share point calendar list using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-calendar

am using below caml query which returns only events not reccuring event

```
query.set_viewXml("<Query><Where>"+
"<DateRangesOverlap>" +
"<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
"<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
"<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />" +
"<FieldRef Name='fRecurrence'/>" +
"<Value  Type='DateTime'><Now /></Value>" +
"</DateRangesOverlap>" +
"</Where>" +
"<queryOptions>" +
" <QueryOptions>" +
  "<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>" +
"</QueryOptions>" +
" <QueryOptions>" +
  "<CalendarDate><Now /></CalendarDate>" +
  + "<RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>" +
"</QueryOptions>" +

"</queryOptions>" +
"<OrderBy>" +
"<FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True' />" +
"</OrderBy></Query>"+"<ViewFields>"
 + "<FieldRef Name='Title' LinkToItem='TRUE'/>"
    + "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />"
     + "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />"    
     + "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceData' />"
     + "<FieldRef Name='fRecurrence' />");
```